# SQL Query doesnt get correct count

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to write a query that would return me for each user how many orders he made and at how many diffrent stores :

```
SELECT user_id,display_name,count(store_id) as stores,count(order_id) as orders 
FROM `orders` natural join users 
where user_id NOT IN (7,766,79) 
group by user_id 
order by orders desc
```

It seem to me that this query should do it but for some reason i get same values in the orders and stores columns (and i have double checked that there should be a diffrence). Any one can help with that?

BTW, order_id is primary key, store_id and user_id are foreign keys on orders.

EDIT:

```
SELECT user_id,display_name,count(distinct store_id) as stores,count(order_id) as orders 
    FROM `orders` natural join users 
    where user_id NOT IN (7,766,79) 
    group by user_id 
    order by orders desc
```

worked, can any one explain why would i have to add distinct keyword in this case?

RESOLVED:

using comments by @McAdam331 i understood that the original query counts the rows with the same user id in both counts, and since post_ids are unique, the the unique ids count is the same as row count, while store_id which can have doubles doesnt have same count as the row count. therefore using distinct solved the problem.

Comment: Try the query without the "display_name" field. What I would do is run it without the display_name and then take the results of that query and join those results against the same table to get the display_name back into the results. Not as efficient as what you are trying to do but that should solve for the correct count.

Comment: @mba12 I understand your concern, and in most cases it'd be true, but if `user_id` is a primary key and each user has only one display name, this query will work fine.

Comment: @mba12 It's too late for me to edit, but you are right that if it's not one-to-one between user_id and display_name they shouldn't be grouped like this, which I wanted to reemphasize for the OP because I've been mistaken before haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `COUNT(*)` to get number of orders, and `COUNT(DISTINCT store_id)` to get the number of stores:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.display_name, COUNT(*) AS numOrders, COUNT(DISTINCT store_id) AS numStores
FROM orders o
JOIN users u
...
```

The reason your query fails is because you're omitting `DISTINCT` on store_id. Because for every row you have a store_id and an order_id, you have the same number of store_ids and order_ids in each group. However, that's not what you're really looking for, you're looking for the number of `DISTINCT` store_ids.

If it's possible for the user to have the same order_id twice (though it doesn't make sense to me) you can add the DISTINCT keyword in that count function too.

Comment: adding distinct keyword helped, but why did i have to add that?

Comment: Because think about it like this, each row has an order_id, and a store_id. If you count them, they are the same amount because it's the same number of rows. What your first example did was count the total number of store_ids (meaning store one is counted each time it appears), while mine counts the distinct number of store_ids (store one will only be counted once).

Answer (score 0):

You've got it backwards. Start with `users` and join to `orders`. Something like this:

```
SELECT users.user_id, display_name,
count(DISTINCT store_id) as store_count,
count(order_id) as order_count
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.user_id=users.user_id
where users.user_id NOT IN (7,766,79) 
group by users.user_id 
order by order_count desc;
```

Note the use of `DISTINCT` within the `store_count` because you may have multiple orders from the same store.